# Rails3 - Given a Form that allows for Updating/Creating - How Delete/Destroy a record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following for which allows for creating or updating a record:

```
<%=form_for [:project, @permission], :remote => true do |f| %>
... You can change roles in the form... (This works great for new or existing records)
<% end %>
```

Inside the form, I want to provide an option to delete/destroy the permission. So I added:

```
<%= link_to 'remove from the team', [:project, @permission], :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

But that's not working, erroring...

It renders as follows:

```
<a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure?" href="/projects/4/permissions/useronproject">remove from the team</a>
```

Error Message:
NoMethodError in PermissionsController#destroy
undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass

Also the params being passed are only:
_method delete
auth token....

So I'm not sure how Rails would know what to delete?

regarding the permissionsController. I do have a destory:

def destroy

```
@permission.destroy

respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

end

Any thoughts on this one? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the permission id in your url is not an integer but the name (or a permalink) of the permission.

Have you set something like

```
def to_param
  permalink
end
```

in your permission model?

The error returned tells that the @permission is set to nil (meaning that no permission is found with such id). In your destroy action you need to retrieve your permission by this permalink/name, something like:

```
def destroy
  @permission = Permission.find_by_permalink(params[:id])
  @permission.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```